# Is there a SPARQL query to yield the total number of items (in the database)?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

using this [SPARQL query on Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20Number%20of%20items%20with%20P31%20%28instance%20of%29%20being%20Q15284%20%28municipality%29%0ASELECT%20%28COUNT%28%3Fitem%29%20AS%20%3Fitem%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%28wdt%3AP31%29%20wd%3AQ15284%20.%20%20%20%20%0A%7D)

```
# Number of items with P31 (instance of) being Q15284 (municipality)
SELECT (COUNT(?item) AS ?item) WHERE {    
  ?item (wdt:P31) wd:Q15284 .    
}
```

the result has one row with the only one colum count at the moment indicatas `4248`.

I would not only know the number of those items in the database that are limited by some attribute, but indeed the number of all items

```
SELECT (COUNT(?item) AS ?item) WHERE {    
# empty because I do not want any limitation
}
```

expected result should be `number of all items` in the database.

I attempt to read the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) and it appears that it is not even possible?

Hence the question here, is there a (hackish) way to use SPARQL to select all items, as to be able to count them?

Comment: What do you mean by 'items'? Wikibase items, i. e. URIs of kind `wd:Qxxx`?

Comment: @StanislavKralin yes. What is meant is ?items as if those would have been queried with the first query, *only without limitation by a `WHERE` part*.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11330/16193, replace `wdt:P31` with `wikibase:statements`. See also https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format

Comment: @StanislavKralin just saw it now, looks like the last link is a bit outdated? I mean, according to the link entities are descirbed via `wd:Q3 a wikibase:Item ;` but I can't query for this data: `select * {?s a wikibase:Item} limit 10` is empty

Comment: @AKSW, they say *"WDQS has the data in the format described above, but there are small differences that can be important while writing SPARQL queries: 1. Types (`a` or `rdf:type`) for `wikibase:Item`, `wikibase:Statement`, `wikibase:Reference`... are currently omitted for performance reasons."* https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#WDQS_data_differences

Comment: @StanislavKralin Since all your comments already have drawn a good picture of the situation, maybe it would be possible to condense it into an answer, allowing me to accept its findings and upvote? in other words, thank you for all your effort into drawing light to this what is obscure to me